# p2v v2v v2p tool from open source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, centos, fedora

we have centos, fedora, ubuntu server and desktop we are looking for good open source tool for p2v v2v v2p and we are not using vmware here only we use xen or kvm. Same of the server shifted to new hardware and same of the server on xen or kvm. Can same help me !!

Comment: here is a step-by-step guide on v2p conversion for redhat http://pleasedonttouchthescreen.blogspot.com/2011/08/linux-v2p.html

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mondorescue.org/ try this out!! one of the very good tool

Comment: i have use above tool Rajat it is working for me thanks

Answer (score 6):

I use KVM in production environments at work.
**p2v**, we tend to just copy the hard disk (with dd) from a physical entity to an LVM disk, or iSCSI LUN, then set KVM to boot from that.

**v2v** is easy, if you're using LVM, just snapshot the disk, then clone the VM, edit the domain xml file (easy with libvirtd/virsh), then restart the new clone with the snapshot of the disk.

**v2p**, again, just use dd to copy the hard disk from LVM to a physical disk (or disk array).

- p2v: dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/VolGroup0/virtualDisk
- v2v: lvcreate -L** -s -n snapshot /dev/VolGroup0/original
- v2p: dd if=/dev/VolGroup0/virtualDisk of=/dev/sdb

For dd commands, you may find that you want to set bs=10240 to make copying faster. YMMV and all that.

Comment: "v2v" often means translating between different systems -- so kvm<->VMware, or RHEV, or such; from that perspective, there's a bit more going on than just copying the backing store.

Comment: If the virtualization technology is good enough, the OS shouldn't notice.

Comment: Tom, virtualization technologies tend to provide their own "guest tools" / paravirtual drivers, frequently emulate different hardware, etc. If "good enough" means supporting a superset of the hardware emulated by all your competitors, then maybe that's true, but I'm not so sure that's a reasonable definition.

Comment: Going P2V, from a number of different hardware architectures, I've managed to virtualise the original instance, without any major hiccups.

Answer (score 3):

Richard W.M. Jones of Red Hat (of [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) / [guestfish](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html) fame) [has done (and is doing) substantial work in this area](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/tag/virt-v2v/). His [virt-p2v tool](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-p2v/) is presently withdrawn to undergo rewrite; however, he has documented [a less-automated process](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/poor-mans-p2v/) to be used in the interim.

Patches providing substantial virt-v2v automation between qemu, VMware ESX and RHEV (Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization) have committed to libguestfs recently, so there's quite a lot going on.